# Issue with viewController.presentedViewController in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

My application Navigation controller based. form the 2nd ViewController I do present a pop over with a TableViewController on tap of a row my popover should dismiss(In some instance /Retain in some instance ) and a custom view controller should be presented. This process must be in a common place so I cannot have any delegate here.

for getting top viewController I use following mtd

```
+ (UIViewController*) topView
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
    while (topController.presentedViewController)
    {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }
    return topController;
}
```

Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Now my Question is I want to present my newViewController after the current execution finished executing.

Comment: There is a delegate method of popover which is called when the popover is dismissed.

Comment: Its a central place where I can't have any delegate

Comment: Central place like? let me know the actual representation of the classes.

Comment: It's the class which I m going to present say for an example UIAlertview that is going to be added in window

Comment: What I understand from your post is that you application is Navigation based and from second controller you are going to show a popover which contains a tableview in it and you want to dismiss the popover when the user tap any cell from the tableview. Am I right?

Comment: It's is instance based. Say on tap of 1 row I need to retain and on tap of 2nd row i need to remove popover. In both the case I have to present a view controller.

Comment: what do you mean by retain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67463/discussion-between-idev-and-adeel-ur-rehman).